# Why can one say WLOG assume $R$ is a local ring in Atiyah and MacDonald's 3.15 Exercise?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

In Exercise 3.15 in Atiyah and Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, the ring $R$ can be assumed to be a local ring, because of proposition 3.9.

That proposition states that if $\phi: M \rightarrow N$ is a $R$-module homomorphism, then the following are equivalent:

i) $\phi$ is injective.

ii) $\phi_{\mathfrak p}: M_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow N_{\mathfrak p}$ is injective for each prime ideal $\mathfrak p$.

iii) $\phi_{\mathfrak m}: M_{\mathfrak m} \rightarrow N_{\mathfrak m}$ is injective for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.

I am not sure what does $M_{\mathfrak m}$ mean, and is still searching for it. Also sorry for quoting a link without carefully reading the paragraph.

Comment: Clearly there is not a general principle in ring theory that *every* ring can be assumed to be local in *every* argument. It depends on the context! But in the proof of Theorem 3.1.1 in the linked pdf, the reduction to local rings is clearly explained ("To see this..."). And in the hint to Exercise 3.15 in Atiyah and MacDonald, the reduction is also explained ("By (3.9), we may assume that $A$ is a local ring."). Can you clarify what part of these explanations you find confusing?

Comment: The rest of that first paragraph in the proof, starting "To see this...," is an explanation. Which part of it don't you understand, so we can help clarify.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry for not being careful with the first paragraph of the link. I thought it was a general result. My question is why proposition 3.9 implies one can assume $A$ to be a local ring.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry for not being careful with the first paragraph of the link. I thought it was a general result. My question is why proposition 3.9 implies one can assume $A$ to be a local ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments under the question:

> My question is why proposition 3.9 implies one can assume $A$ to be a local ring.

In that exercise you have an $A$-module homomorphism $\phi:F\to F$ ($F$ is a free $A$-module of rank $n$) which is surjective and want to show that it is injective. Then, by Proposition 3.9, it's enough to show that $\phi_{\mathfrak p}:F_{\mathfrak p}\to F_{\mathfrak p}$ is injective for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $A$. But $F_{\mathfrak p}$ is a free $A_{\mathfrak p}$-module of rank $n$ (why?), and thus one may replace $A$ by $A_{\mathfrak p}$ which is local.

Btw, $M_{\mathfrak m}$ stands for the localization of $M$ at the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.